# Fails to Scaffolding on project which has a reference to edmx

Tags: c#, entity-framework, scaffolding, edmx, t4scaffolding

I have Demo solution with two projects like this :

[image]

I have installed `T4Scaffolding`.`Install-Package T4Scaffolding`

I have added a reference of `AdventureWorksModel` to my `RepoLayer` Project and install EF6 .

---

Now when i try to run the following command :

`scaffold repository AdventureWorksModel.Customer` to my `RepoLayer` Project

I get the following exception :

```
Get-ProjectType : Cannot find a type matching the name
'AdventureWorksModel.Customer'. Try specifying the fully-qualified
type name, including namespace.`
```

although the same command works successfully when i run it on  `AdventureWorksModel` project !

Comment: The fully-qualified name should be `AdventureWorksModel.Sales.Customer`.

Comment: @jstreet i have tried this name but the same exception

Answer (score 3):

Here is the steps which you need to do

1. Class library having AdventureWorksModel EDMX (already present)
2. Class library "RepoLayer" which above AdventureWorksModel library, EF 6 installed (already present)
3. In the "RepoLayer" library, please ***T4Scaffolding.Core.VS2015*** and ***T4Scaffolding.VS2015*** NuGet packages. I hope your using VS 2015
4. Run the scaffolding command **scaffold repository AdvwrksModel.Customer** for "RepoLayer" library. The repository and DbContext class gets created successfully. Here is screenshot

[image: T4 Scaffolding]

Update related to EDMX name from above screen shot
The command

> scaffold repository AdvwrksModel.Customer

gives us important thought "**AdvwrksModel**" is EDMX name and namespace should be "**AdvwrksModel**". Then it will work fine.

From code link provided; After building, it gave same error what you mentioned in question, then after investigation it was namespace issue. Attaching screenshot with points 1, 2, 3, 4 should be "SledModel" i.e. EDMX name. Point 5 is generated repository for Race

I guess this will solve your problem. I am not sure how the namespace was different then EDMX name.

[image: Update EDMX Name]

Comment: i use visual studio 2013

Comment: I used VS 2013 version, ensure that T4Scaffolding and T4Scaffolding.Core have latest version installed from NuGet. I was able to creare repository classes for Customer, Product ... I tried against .NET 4.5 . I tried against .NET 4.0 also, it works properly, maybe if can update T4Scaffolding latest version, they might work.

Comment: I run this command `Install-Package T4Scaffolding` on Package Manage Console , making the default project `RepoLayer`

Comment: try adding them using NuGet T4Scaffolding & T4Scaffolding.Core instead of console.

Comment: I have added `T4Scaffolding.Core.VS2015 and T4Scaffolding.VS2015 ` through the `Nuget` but invain !! ,when i try to run `scaffold repository AdventureWorksModel.Customer` and make the `AdventureWorksModel` the Default project instead of `RepoLayer` it works perfectly !!
Could you tell me What 's the wrong i made please?

Comment: The same problem when i use `code first` rather than `DB First` .
It works when i run the command on the `domain classes` and failed with `data layer` !!

Comment: Can you share the project soln with me? I have a look on that. Running fine on domain classes is very natural but on data layer also it should work.

Comment: I have try another small project with the same error :Here 's the link :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0lf2msjeyq5qnor/SledDogEvent.rar?dl=0

Comment: i use V.S 2013 ,Really grateful for you.

Comment: Have a look at updated solution link. I used VS 2013 and also I have updated my answer for more details. https://www.dropbox.com/s/8w4abc7pq4ligqf/SledDog-Fixed.zip?dl=0